# From one java file compile other java file

Tags: java

here is my case ...i have one xxxxxx.java file when compile and run the file i get output as yyyyyy.java file .....but i need yyyyyy.class file i.e is from xxxxxx.java file should automatically compile it output file and get yyyyyy.class...can this be done in java

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 6, this can be done via the [`JavaCompiler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API in `javax.tools`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the interface from the [tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) package. There are enough [examples](http://www.google.ch/search?q=import+javax.tools.JavaCompiler) on the web, one is here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm